# Constantly getting an email: Cannot read property "0" from undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I am constantly getting emails from "me" with this in it:
`Cannot read property "0" from undefined.`

I think it has something to do with Google Apps script because it started when I tried to code something. (for details: I was trying to code a "Contact Us Form" for my website)

I cant post images yet because of my reputation but I have a few links here:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGv6e.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3hJE.png

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to post the code you wrote;  as it is, there isn't enough information here to help you.

Comment: @RichardII That's the strange part, i have deleted the app script and still getting these emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn off your trigger.  Go to *script.google.com*.   Create a blank script.  Once you are in the Apps Script Editor click on "Resources"->"All your triggers"

You will see all triggers associated with your account.  You can click on the X icon next to the ones you want to delete.

Comment: Very great thanks for this answer. I had something on a timer that would send me an email every hour. Now I can live again without spam. Thanks!